# iOS, RealityKit, failed to move Entity towards a certain direction, with MotionSystem update function

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I am trying and trying to make my **Entity** move towards some previously described destination.

The **entity** moves on a microlevel over and over again but never reaches its destination. DestinationSystem checks with its update function if the **Entity** is close enough so it can choose a new destination for it.

I kindly ask you for help as I am absolutely out of ideas.

Here is my DestinationSystem's update function.
This system will **only** chose the current destination for the entity and then checks if the entity reached it.

```swift
func update(context: SceneUpdateContext) {

        let walkers = context.scene.performQuery(Self.query)

        walkers.forEach({ entity in

            guard var walker = entity.components[DestinationComponent.self] as? DestinationComponent,

                  let _ = entity.components[MotionComponent.self] as? MotionComponent else { return }

            defer {
                entity.components[DestinationComponent.self] = walker
            }

            // set the default destination to 0
            var distanceFromDestination: Float = 0

            // check if walker component for this specific entity has any destination
            if let destination = walker.destination {
                // distract distance from it
                distanceFromDestination = entity.distance(from: destination)
            }

            // check if the distance still is. If its tiny, then lets choose another distance
            if distanceFromDestination < 0.02 {
                var fixedDestination = SIMD3<Float>.spawnPoint(from: entity.transform.translation, radius: 0.7)
                fixedDestination.y = Float(0)

                // If there is any obstacle on the way to the destination, set that obstacle as the destination so it wont pass it, perhaps through the wall
                let obstacles = context.scene.raycast(
                    from: entity.position,
                    to: fixedDestination,
                    query: .nearest,
                    mask: .sceneUnderstanding,
                    relativeTo: nil
                )

                if let nearest = obstacles.first {
                    fixedDestination = nearest.position
                    fixedDestination.y = Float(0)
                }

                walker.destination = fixedDestination
            }
        })
    }
```

Here is my **MotionSystem**. Constant variable **s** calculates current translation to cross and multiplies it by the deltaTime of the context and 0.03 which I choose as a speed.

```swift
    func update(context: SceneUpdateContext) {

        context.scene.performQuery(Self.query).forEach { entity in
            let fixedDelta: Float = Float(context.deltaTime)
            guard let _ = entity.components[MotionComponent.self] as? MotionComponent,
                  let walker = entity.components[DestinationComponent.self] as? DestinationComponent
            else { return }

            var newTransform = entity.transform

            let s = (walker.destination! - entity.transform.translation) * 0.03 * fixedDelta

            newTransform.translation = s
            newTransform.translation.y = Float(0)

            entity.move(to: newTransform, relativeTo: entity.parent)
        }
    }
```

I believe it should take my Entity frame by frame to the destination point, then choose another one. It never will again.

Unless my math is terribly off?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: there's not much point using .move when the animation is 0.03s (1 frame)

Comment: Instead, just try updating the entity position. Try updating s to instead be a linear interpolation from current translation to destination with a interpolate value of 0.1, see if that makes it any better.

Comment: Hey Max, that method actually performs teleportation without the animation instantly. Other walk around I found was to move the Entity with the animation and create a conditional so it won't move it again up until animation is finished. But doesn't exactly allow manipulating the route while moving the Entity.

Comment: If your animation lasts 0.03s, then there would be almost no difference than updating its position without an animation. This is because the animation is 1/33s, so there's only two frames involved - start and end.
an animation breaks down steps between points A and B into positions per frame

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. If you use method .move without the duration parameter, the translation is instant, there is no animation process involved.